# nested sql query to calculate variance on sum

Tags: sql, sas

I want to calculate variance of sum of sales for each customer across diff product category. below is an example. I am getting error. Please help me on how can i do it in a step.

ab - customer
bc - product category
bd - amount

```
data a;
input ab$ bc$ bd;
datalines;
a x 5
a x 6
a y 9
a y 6
a y 5
a z 9
a z 8
b z 6
b z 9
b y 8
b y 6
b x 6
b x 6
b x 7
b z 8
b z 9
```

;

```
run;

proc sql;
    create table b as select ab , var (sum_bd) from(
    from (select ab, bc, sum(bd) as sum_bd from a group by ab, bc))
    group by ab;
run;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).                                    ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ), ',', ANSIMISS, CROSS, FULL, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, NATURAL, NOMISS, RIGHT. ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `from` clauses.  Try this syntactically correct version:

```
proc sql;
    create table b as
        select ab, var(sum_bd)
        from (select ab, bc, sum(bd) as sum_bd
              from a
              group by ab, bc
             ) a
        group by ab;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no VAR function in MySQL, it's VAR_POP or VAR_SAMP.

Comment: i am using proc sql in sas, var seems to be a valid function